# Python strange override behaviour for "__" functions

Tags: python, function, private

I found "strange" behaviour in Python overriding for "__" functions

```
class A(object):

    def foo1(self):
        print "foo1 A"
        self.test1()

    def foo2(self):
        print "foo2 A"
        self.__test2()

    def test1(self):
        print "test1 A"

    def __test2(self):
        print "test2 A"

class B(A):
    def test1(self):
        print "test1 B"

    def __test2(self):
        print "test2 B"

ia = A()
ib = B()
ib.foo1()
ib.foo2()
```

gives as result:

```
foo1 A
test1 B
foo2 A
test2 A
```

instead of:

```
foo1 A
test1 B
foo2 A
test2 B
```

is it normal behaviour for Python "__" functions?

Comment: this is one of many good reasons _not to use_ `__foo` names.  they aren't "private", they're just confusing and weird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour you see is the **stated intent** of using a leading double underscore name in a class attribute or method.

Names with a leading double underscore are 'mangled'; have the name of the class prefixed, *explicitly to prevent name clashes* with subclasses.

See [*Reserved classes of identifiers*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) in the reference documentation:

> `__*`
>   Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a mangled form **to help avoid name clashes between “private” attributes of base and derived classes**.

(*emphasis mine*)

Also see the [*Identifiers* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) of the expressions documentation:

> **Private name mangling**: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`. This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used. If the transformed name is extremely long (longer than 255 characters), implementation defined truncation may happen. If the class name consists only of underscores, no transformation is done.